# Maven3 system.property user.home vs environment variable HOME

Tags: maven, environment-variables, system-properties

There seems to be a problem with the system properties in Maven. It seems that system properties don't correspond to  the environment variables.

The situation is that I would like to the change the absolute location of the user-specific `settings.xml` file, as the Maven document says

> If you need to create user-specific settings from scratch, it’s
>   easiest to copy the global settings from your Maven installation to
>   your ${user.home}/.m2 directory

which means that the only way to change the absolute location of the user-specific file is to change the `user.home` property. But it seems that this is not exactly the `HOME` or `HOMEPATH` environment variable. In fact, I deleted all the environment variables such as `HOME` and `HOMEPATH`, and run mvn using `mvn -X` just to see the user-specific `settings.xml` that mvn uses. The result is the following (I am in Windows 7 and I run the command in cmd.exe):

[image]

Maven still finds a `user.home` property, however, I haven't set such a environment variable. To verify this, I then run the `set` command to see all the environment variables but find nothing about the path `d:\Userfiles\xili\` which is used by Maven as the `user.home` system property. By the way, there is no settings.xml file in this path, because I haven't put any file in this path.

How maven figure out such a path as `user.home`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is here!

http://www.timehat.com/javas-user-home-is-wrong-on-windows/

In fact, in **Windows**, the JVM uses the **PATH_TO_DESKTOP_FOLDER_AS_SET_IN_THE_REGISTRY** as the *reference* to determine wheres is the `user.home`.

`user.home` is just the parent folder of the above path. That't it, this has nothing to do with the `HOME` or `HOMEPATH` enviroment variable.

In the source code of Maven, there should be some code like `System.getProperty('user.home')`.